# Copy/paste table into gmail

Tags: r, gmail, rstudio

This is probably an easy answer, but I can't find anything online about it. Is there an easy way to copy/paste a table from the R console to an email message?

Comment: And get it looking halfway decent, of course...

Comment: As the questioner you should not use comments to clarify the question. That's waht the [edit] link is for. You should, however, clarify by what is meant by the word "table". Are you trying to paste the screen output for a data.frame? Is the problem with misalignment of columns due to different fonts? Or ... what... exactly?

Comment: I the purpose of the mail is for the receiver to import your data in R, use `dput` instead.

Comment: Use a fixed width font.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Markdown Here](http://markdown-here.com/) extension, available for Chrome and Firefox (the last time I checked). Used in conjunction with `kable` from "knitr" (already recommended) you can get a nicely formatted table in seconds.

After installation, you will be able to find a "markdown toggle" option in your right-click context menu when composing an email.

Here's a GIF to show the steps.

[image]

Do this often? Save yourself the copying step at least by creating a helper function to write to the clipboard (this is Windows only, but you can [expand on the function](https://github.com/mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab/blob/master/R/clipboard.R) if you wanted compatibility with other OSes).

```
gmailTable <- function(indf) writeClipboard(capture.output(knitr::kable(indf)))
```

Then, in R, just do `gmailTable(mtcars)`, switch over to Gmail, paste the contents of the clipboard into the message area, and markdown toggle as before :-)

By the way, "Markdown Here" also lets you use a shortcut to convert whatever is in the message area to HTML. By default, I believe it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>.

Comment: this seems Windows-specific, as there is no `writeClipboard` in standard R / Mac

Comment: @DimaLituiev, Yes, and the answer does specifically say "Windows only". However, in the "expand on the function" link (https://github.com/mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab/blob/master/R/clipboard.R) I've shared something that should be usable with other OSes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use knitr and kable in RStudio (New file R markdown, output format html):

````
---
title: "attaching pretty R tables to your gmail message"
date: "4 Jun 2015"
output: html_document
---

This is an example of a pretty table, produced with Knitr in RStudio:

 * RStudio: New file R markdown, output format html
 * open in (chrome) browser
 * save as complete html
 * attach the html to your gmail message

```{r kable}
library(knitr)
carstable = head(mtcars)
kable(carstable)
```
````

This example [published on RPubs](http://rpubs.com/ronnydw/84660)

Answer (score -1):

In RStudio, you can use `View(table)` and highlight the entire window and paste that into your email. Here's what it looked like for me with the `cars` dataset:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for two reasons:

First, it doesn't look nearly as nice when I copy/paste. Maybe something to do with using gmail?

Second, I've got a twoway table, and it does not print it out in a nice format.

Comment: Copy pasting from RStudio viewer distorts the table in gmail.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I can think of is either go into knitr/xtable/latex or save the data.frame that you want to show as a csv file and send that as an attachment in you e-mail. The first option will require a lot of effort for just one table, but if you think you might need this kind of things more often it might be worth the time.